# Using vim with putty: Color schemes do not change the background color

Tags: vim, putty

I am trying to use vim on a remote server with putty, and am working on getting my settings set up. My problem is that vim seems unable to change the background color. I have tried using :set background=light and using a 256-color scheme. The text color changes with the color scheme, but not not the background color.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing ‘Use background colour to erase screen’ option in PuTTY Settings.